# Angular Material md-checkbox group issues

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive, angular-material

Allow md-checkbox to iterate over array of elements as follows:

```
<md-checkbox ng-repeat="cat in categorias" value="{{cat.id}}" ng-checked="{{cat.id.indexOf(item.cats) > -1}}" ng-model="item.cats">{{cat.name}}</md-checkbox>
```

and populate model with a list of selected values such as http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Feedback appreciated...

Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/t4jDNDnq6NObaeLgR6kK?p=preview

For now, no solution, I am using [checklist directive](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/).

Comment: check example already present on angular-material site (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.checkbox)

Comment: Thx, i change more options.. finally sucess :D

Comment: The sample mentioned by nitin is now located here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Previously, checklist-model couldn't be used on `<md-checkbox>`. Starting with version **0.3.0** this is possible. Check out the new version.

Comment: Can i use checklist-model in Angular 2 <md-checkbox> ??

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it is designed for angular1.